# So why do SSD disks have a reputation for power efficiency?

Tags: solid-state-devices

Why do SSD disks have a reputation for power efficiency? I've just looked at some the spec sheets for SSD and mechanical hard disks. In a lot of cases, the even during idle state, SSDs use slightly more watts than their mechanical counterparts? Can anyone explain this one?

Comment: Links to datasheets please.

Comment: https://www.toshiba.eu/Contents/Toshiba_teg/EU/Others/HDD_datasheets/L200_Mobile_Hard_Drive_Datasheet.pdf    1TB .55W idle state

Comment: https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/16376/~/sandisk-ultra-ii-ssd-specifications  960GB SSD  .85W idle state

Comment: daikin - The idle power of the Sandisk SSD is stated as 85mW which is equivalent to 0.085W....only about 15% of the typical idle current for the HDD.

Comment: Read that again.  The Sandisk idle is 85mW.  The Toshiba idle is 550mW.  Seems like a clear win on idle.

Comment: "Sandisk  960GB SSD .85W idle state" - no, it's 0.085W

Comment: ok, thanks Michael, JRE and Bruce - I misread that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There might be few things to consider as why SSD have a reputation of higher power efficiency. For example, compare [WD 2.5" HDD "black series"](http://maxdata.com/content/orders/Western%20Digital/pdf/FI005W08.pdf) with [Samsung 860 series](https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/global.semi.static/Samsung_SSD_860_EVO_Data_Sheet_Rev1.pdf) SATA drives:

WD, 250/500 GB:

[image]

Samsung 860, same 250/500 GB:

[image]

First, as one can see, Idle for HDD is 800 mW, while idle for SSD is 50 mW, or HDD consumes 16X more. Note, that most time the drives in PC idle. So we have 16 X power savings already there, roughly speaking.

Now, power during read/write operations is listed as 2 W for HDD, and 2.5 W for SSD. However, write performance of 2.5" HDDs is about 25% of SSDs, see [WD wd5000lplx report](https://images10.newegg.com/UploadFilesForNewegg/itemintelligence/Western%20Digital/96nd500g_st_wd7kg_Testreport1447838970400.pdf) as compared to [Samsung 860 report](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/samsung-860-evo-ssd-review,5446-3.html). Sustained sequential reads/writes of 2.5" HDD rarely exceed 120-130 MBytes/s, while SSD makes steady 500-550 MBytes/s.

It means that if you have an application that transfers certain amount of data per second, the SSD will take only 1/4 of active time as compared to HDD. Therefore effectively the SSD will use 0.5 W where the HDD will use 2 W.

I think this is a good reason to designate SSDs as ~ 4X more efficient than equivalent HDDs. (Disclaimer: few times in my career I supplied benchmark data for marketing, so please forgive me for some stretches :-))

Comment: Thank you for those interesting comparisons. I do always chuckle at the MTBF stats issued by the marketing depts. of disk companies!

Comment: @daikin, so I take it that you are not satisfied with my interpretation?

Comment: no, far from it. I was just commenting on how you had to supply benchmark figures for a marketing dept. I know people who did this in previous roles and I know how sometimes they demand that hardware or software stats are slightly stretched!

Comment: @daikin, no, stats stretching is not allowed. Otherwise there could be crazy people in some libertarian countries who would sue the company for "misrepresentation". The art of "benchmarketing" is to identify system conditions when your product behaves the best, so anyone who follows the test conditions (in fine print) can reproduce the numbers. Although some spin might be required from verbal engineering.